# How can we run I write Cakephp Migrations for database connection type?

Tags: cakephp, cakedc

I am using CakeDc Migrations plugin for database migration. my application is using two databases. so configured it in database.php. I have written many migrations which co-ordinate with the database1(default connection ) and its working fine. Now I want to write one migration which co-ordinate with database2(I want to run these queries only on database2 ) . how Can I differentiate? at what level ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the help text and documentation.

```
--connection, -c           Overrides the 'default' connection of the
                           MigrationVersion
--migrationConnection, -i  Overrides the 'default' connection of the
                           CakeMigrations that are applied
```

There are more options, just type `cake migrations.migration` and read what it shows. There is also a lot documentation in the /Docs folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but I am using above options and it is executing migrations on that new db as well. but I want to write migrations itself for different connections. here using above option it will execute all migrations on both databases. I want seperate migrations for these two databases.