# Managing schema and migrations for multiple connections without using plugin directory in CakePHP 2

Tags: migration, schema, cakephp-2.0, cakedc

I'm using schema management tool (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/schema-management-and-migrations.html) and CakeDC's migration plugin (https://github.com/CakeDC/migrations) in CakePHP 2.6.2

As this user, [How can we run I write Cakephp Migrations for database connection type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990417/how-can-we-run-i-write-cakephp-migrations-for-database-connection-type), I want to deal with two or more databases to manage schema and migrations, and by specifying plugins to "write schema files to", it is possible to differentiate two database connections to manage.

But I find it confusing if I have to store schema.php and migration files in "plugins". I have to create and maintain plugins in app/Plugin directory, for managing schema.php and migration files and keeping Config/Schema and Config/Migration directories.

Is it possible to manage schema and migration files elsewhere using above tools, with or without using the plugin options?

For example, suppose I manage two connections, db_connection1 and db_connection2,  I want to build a directory structure like this:

```
app/schema_management/DbConnection1/Config/{Schema,Migration}/*.php
app/schema_management/DbConnection2/Config/{Schema,Migration}/*.php
```

instead of creating two "plugins" to keep like this:

```
app/Plugin/DbConnection1/Config/{Schema,Migration}/*.php
app/Plugin/DbConnection2/Config/{Schema,Migration}/*.php
```